# Design: Better way to return an array of child objects from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database-design

I have an object in C#

```
class Products {
    public int ProductId {get; private set;}
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public List<ProductImages> Images {get; set;}
}

class ProductImages{
    public string Channel { get; set; }
    public string ImageType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image {get; set;}
}
```

Now there is already a procedure for GetProducts which returns everything but the images, otherwise I would probably turn the entire query into an XML object and do serialization, though I have been asked not to.

The decision is:

- Create a new column in this query and only that column is XML (or JSON) and then just deserialize the array of ProductImages
- Make a separate call to the database to get the child object.  That is pass in Product Id and return a table of ProductImages and on the server side loop through the table and create child objects.

Does the cost of deserializing an object out weight the cost of hitting the database connection again and looping through a table of records?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first solution is better. Usually it's better to avoid hitting the database repeatedly.
In any case it's easy to set up a small test, and measure time and memory use for both options, and select which one fits better

Answer (score 0):

This decision should be driven by the model design considerations, rather than implementation considerations.

If all of the following is true, use a single BLOB for all images in the `Product` table:

- **Images are never shared among products** - this may be useful when multiple versions of the same product exist, but they look the same, e.g. different model years of the same product,
- **Images are never updated individually** - this includes situations when you add new images, remove old images, replace images with new ones, etc.
- **Never need a subset of product images** - this may be desirable when you show different images of the same product in different markets, e.g. products labeled in different languages

Otherwise, make a separate table attached to `Product` in many-to-one relationship for non-shared images or with an additional many-to-many table for shared images.

In some cases it may be beneficial to remove `Images` from `Product`, and opt for adding an API similar to `GetProductImages(productId, additionalCriteria)` instead, with `additionalCriteria` representing the context in which you want to use images (e.g. the market).

Finally, you may want to opt for lazy loading of images in situations when some use cases do not show images at all - for example, drop-down lists may include just the `DisplayName`, while a more detailed view may include images. This consideration applies to both normalized and denormalized (all images in a BLOB) solutions.

Comment: Thank you for this.  In my case the structure is set we have a product table, a media table and then a table that joins the two together (so images can be shared).  But lazy loading may be the answer, then it would be a separate call to the DB

Comment: @Mike The main consideration for lazy loading is whether or not you need images in all situations. This does mean a separate call to DB. Another solution would be to have a separate class, say, `ProductDescriptor` that has all data from `Product` but no images. This would make the API user to decide on whether or not to read images, letting you to avoid a separate roundtrip to DB when images are needed.